# Using a Arducam 64 MP in Motion

Tags: motion

I'm having trouble using an [Arducam 64MP](https://www.arducam.com/64mp-ultra-high-res-camera-raspberry-pi/).  I've gotten `libcamera-*` commands to work, but when I start Motion, I two errors:

- Seems like the default palette doesn't work

```
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Sep 20 21:27:00] v4l2_pixfmt_select: Configuration palette index 17 (YU12) for 640x480 doesn't work.
```

- The camera device doesn't open

```
[1:ml1] [ERR] [VID] [Sep 20 21:27:00] vid_start: V4L2 device failed to open
[1:ml1] [WRN] [ALL] [Sep 20 21:27:00] motion_init: Could not fetch initial image from camera
```

Can someone else with this setup offer some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

After more googling, it seems like `libcamera` is written in C++, so `motion` does not plan to support it (see [here](https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion/issues/1434))

There is also `motionplus`, which I haven't tested yet.